# How can l resume a detached screen after switching off my laptop?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I want to launch a program on a remote server (Amazon AWS), but the calculation takes about 50h. So I would like to launch my program, switch off my computer then come back to see the results once finished.

I did the following command:

```
screen
ssh -i ubuntu@ip-address
python2 my_code.py
```

and then I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to detach.

After that, I switch off my computer. When I switch it on and run

```
screen -r
```

I get the following

```
There is no screen to be resumed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switched off your laptop, then that `screen` process has terminated. You should run `screen` on the AWS instance:

```
ssh ubuntu@ip
# Then
screen
python ...
```

Ultimately, `screen` should run on whichever system is likely to remain running. If that's your laptop, then run `screen` on the laptop. If that's the AWS instance, then run it on the AWS instance.

Comment: Hi @muru, thanks for your answer. if l understand well , if the process is still running : l can switch my laptop and when l get back l run screen -r and l get the process ; othersiwe l should run screen on aws ?

Comment: @vincent75 "if the process is still running"? No: switch off your laptop and the screen running on your laptop dies. You can't connect to that again.